# Finding Old Value of Item in Firebase After Update

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a simple app to do CRUD work with Firebase- Add, update, and delete. I have completed all of them, except for the fact I have an issue with update.

I'm able to get the reference to the proper user when updating the child value, and have it successfully update in the firebase console. This is the code I used for that:

```
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users")
    ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] else { return }

        if self.firstNameField.text == dictionary["firstname"] as? String
        {
            if let lastname = dictionary["lastname"]
            {
                print("Here is the lastname of the current person \(lastname)")

                guard let firstname = self.firstNameField.text, lastname = self.lastNameField.text, dateOfBirth = self.dateOfBirthField.text, zipcode = Int(self.zipcodeField.text!) else
                {
                    print("Form not valid")
                    return
                }

                let properties: [String: AnyObject] = ["firstname": firstname, "lastname": lastname, "Date of Birth": dateOfBirth, "Zipcode": zipcode]

                let currentKey = snapshot.key
                ref.child(currentKey).updateChildValues(properties, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

                    if error != nil
                    {
                        print("We have an error updating the data \(error)")
                    }

                    print("We were able to update the entry in the reference \(ref)")

                })
            }
        }

    }, withCancelBlock: nil)
```

My issue is the TableViewController not updating the proper index as soon as I dismiss the EditViewController. The tableview.reloadData() method isn't working for that, so I figure I need to fix it in my ChildChanged method. Here is the code for that:

```
ref.observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        print("One of the entries were changed so we're reloading the table view")

        if let firstname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("firstname"), lastname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("lastname")
        {
            let fullname = "\(firstname) \(lastname)"
            self.names[I_Need_This_Index] = fullname
            print(fullname)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }, withCancelBlock: nil)
```

The code above is in a method called observePeople(), which is called during the viewDidLoad method. The observePeople() method handled the ChildAdded, ChildRemoved, and ChildChanged notifications.

How can I properly navigate to the old index and change the old value to the new value so that the table view updates properly?

Comment: Just change the `dataSource[indexOfCellThatChanged]` at the time you are updating the values.-> Call for reloadTableView.

Comment: what would I change it to? And how would I get access to it from my other view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a temporary solution I have that only works once and then doesn't work after that:

I create a global string variable called "ogFullName" and set it to the full name during the child added code. Then in my child changed code, I set "ogFullName" to the index of the element I'm trying to change. It's a bit difficult for me to explain it in words, so here is the code:

```
var ogFullname:String?

func observePeople()
{
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users")
    ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock:
    { (snapshot) in

        if let firstname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("firstname"), lastname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("lastname")
        {
            let fullname = "\(firstname) \(lastname)"
            self.ogFullname = fullname //the old name
...
```

And here in my ChildChanged code:

```
 ref.observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        print("One of the entries were changed so we're reloading the table view")

        if let firstname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("firstname"), lastname = snapshot.value?.objectForKey("lastname")
        {
            let fullname = "\(firstname) \(lastname)"
            if let ogname = self.ogFullname
            {
                if let originalIndex = self.names.indexOf(agnate) //finding the index of the unchanged name
                {
                    self.names[originalIndex] = fullname //setting the old name to the changed one
                }
```

This solution only works once per build. After that it continues the same behavior of the updates showing on the console but not the table view.